# Add rules (filters) to ftp programs to avoid uploading certain files/folders

Tags: ftp, uploading, filtering

i use Filezilla as my ftp client, but this question goes to any other client that could be useful.
Can i (in any client) add rules (filters) to an ftp program to avoid upload of certain files or folders? 
For example: Expression web creates those annoying _vti_cnf folders, or, certain folders in which i have the original version of a picture without a watermark that i don't want to upload.

Example, i have a folder A, that has sub folders "original" and "current", i would like to add a filter, so every time i select A to be uploaded, "original" wouldn't go, but "current would".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filename filters provide a way to filter out files and directories with respect to both visibility and transfers.

http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Filename_Filters

Comment: I can't believe it was there all time and i couldn't see it.
Its hard to believe it's not under settings, just on the bar menu itself. Thanks mate. Cheers

Comment: Actually I didn't know where it was...google is my friend :o)

Comment: My friend also, or so i thought =/

Comment: I just found out, through using another computer, that filezilla still sends those folders/files. It just doesn't display them.

Comment: Not so.  It doesn't upload them.  I just tested.  Applied a filter, folder appeared empty.  Uploaded entire folder, empty folder on remote.

Comment: You're right @Steve, i'm sorry, it was a backup version. Thanks again, i apologize.